# SQL Server: How I create a horizontal table

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example if I have the next table:

```
| sensorid |date| value |
-------------------------
|    65000 | 00 |    32 |
|    65000 | 01 |    40 |
|    65000 | 02 |    35 |
|    65000 | 03 |    37 |
|    65000 | 04 |    39 |
|    65001 | 00 |    06 |
|    65001 | 01 |    10 |
|    65001 | 02 |    15 |
|    65001 | 03 |    26 |
|    65001 | 04 |    39 |
```

I want to convert to this table?

```
| SENSORID | 00 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 |
------------------------------------
| 65000    | 32 | 40 | 35 | 37 | 39 |
| 65001    | 6  | 10 | 15 | 26 | 39 |
```

Is there a special method or I have to find a way to iterate a while?

I need help.

Comment: I would recommend using a language (php, python, or whatever) that can interact with the database. Then you can read all the ID's from `data` and generate the table definition systematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIVOT does exactly what you need:

```
SELECT sensorid, 
       [00], [01], [02], [03], [04]
FROM MyTable
PIVOT
(
  MAX(value)
  FOR date IN ([00], [01], [02], [03], [04])
) AS PivotTable;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank for your answer, but my problem is: if exist many "sensorid" and I want to iterate with a "while". How I get all sensorid?

Comment: So is the number of the columns dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but you won't get a dynamic query easily.

As the comments to your question hints, this might be easier to accomplish with the programming language you're actually executing the SQL from.

If you know beforehand all the "categories" (date column in your case), you can create an SQL like this:

```
select
    sensorid,
    max(case when date = 0 then value else 0 end) as date0,
    max(case when date = 1 then value else 1 end) as date1,
    max(case when date = 2 then value else 2 end) as date2,
    max(case when date = 3 then value else 3 end) as date3,
    max(case when date = 4 then value else 4 end) as date4
from
    yourtable
group by
    sensorid
```

Here's a complete [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) script that you can experiment with:

```
USE master
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysdatabases WHERE name = 'SO16639641')
    DROP DATABASE SO16639641
GO

CREATE DATABASE SO16639641
GO

USE SO16639641
GO

CREATE TABLE original
(
    sensorid    int,
    date_       int,
    value       int
)
GO

INSERT INTO original
VALUES
    (65000, 00, 32),
    (65000, 01, 40),
    (65000, 02, 35),
    (65000, 03, 37),
    (65000, 04, 39),
    (65001, 00, 06),
    (65001, 01, 10),
    (65001, 02, 15),
    (65001, 03, 26),
    (65001, 04, 39)
GO

SELECT
    sensorid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN date_ = 0 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS date0,
    MAX(CASE WHEN date_ = 1 THEN value ELSE 1 END) AS date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN date_ = 2 THEN value ELSE 2 END) AS date2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN date_ = 3 THEN value ELSE 3 END) AS date3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN date_ = 4 THEN value ELSE 4 END) AS date4
FROM
    original
GROUP BY
    sensorid
GO
```

Or download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qilllrupnp1d57h/zm0x81QDQ1).

I also added a dynamic version, which will figure out which date columns to add according to the data. A bit more involved, but you can find both scripts at the above link.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want to get the readings from each sensor per day? you could do this quite happily by altering your select statement to order the output

select date, sensorid, value from [tablename] order by date asc, sensorid asc;

```
DATE SENSORID VALUE
00 65000 32
00 65001 06
01 65000 40
01 65001 10
```

if it actually needs to be horizontally formatted I'd suggest looking at PIVOT on MSDN